# How to know when the Chrome window has the focus (and there's a plugin in the document)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus, dom-events, silverlight-5.0

I have an app that needs to notify it's users when it won't process keyboard events. I'm constantly monitoring the `document.hasFocus()` which works as I need in Firefox and IE (!), but doesn't in Chrome.

If I start at the location bar, `document.hasFocus()` returns false; when I <kbd>TAB</kbd>, the document containing the plugin instance gets the focus and `document.hasFocus()` returns true; now if I <kbd>TAB</kbd> again, the plugin (Silverlight in this case) gets the focus, and `document.hasFocus()` returns false.

Maybe that is the correct behavior and the other two browsers are incorrectly returning true, but if that is the case, how can I know when the browser window has the focus?

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this :

```
var hasFocus = false,
    toggleFocus = function() {
        hasFocus = !hasFocus
    };
window.addEventListener( 'focus', toggleFocus );
window.addEventListener( 'blur', toggleFocus );
```

Comment: It’s better to use the `blur` and `focus` events than to constantly monitor `document.hasFocus()`, but the blur event indeed seems to be triggered when you focus on the location bar

Comment: I'm monitoring the hasFocus() form the SL side as I have to monitor Xaml focus too...I've tried something similar to what you've posted before, but didn't work. Will try with your code, tough, maybe using addEventListener makes a difference.

Comment: Didn't work. My previous attempt was using window.onfocus and window.onblur to assign functions that kept track of the focus, but that didn't work either. The problem seems to be that Chrome thinks of the plugin as another window, and thus reports its focus stolen...

Comment: That’s too bad ! I’m sorry, I don’t have any other suggestions…

Comment: this helped me work around http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64846 (I initialized hasFocus to true though)